# find the id of the closest element jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a HTML in my page something like below

```
<dl>
<dt>
    <label>Orientation<span class="required">&nbsp;*</span></label>
 </dt>
<dd>
    <select name="options[3323]" id="select_3323">
     <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
     <option value="9257">Landscape </option>
     <option value="9256">Portrait </option>
   </select> 
   <div class="tagtip-question" id="select_description_3323" style="display:none;"> 
    </div>                                            
</dd>
</dl>
```

I want to an ID attribute of the select element based on a label element. If a page has an element  and it contains text Orientation fetch an ID of the next select element that is select_3323.

I have tried below code but it is not working

```
var element = jQuery("label:contains('Orientation')");
if(element.length == 1){

 alert(element.next('select').attr('id'))

  }
```

Anyone here to help me on this?

Comment: The select isn't the next sibling, it's the child of the next sibling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to parent using `.closest()` (what you already did), and then you can use [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
alert(element.closest('dt').siblings('dd').find('select').attr('id'))
```

***Working snippet:-***

```js
var element = jQuery("label:contains('Orientation')");
if(element.length == 1){
  alert(element.closest('dt').siblings('dd').find('select').attr('id'))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl>
<dt>
    <label>Orientation<span class="required">&nbsp;*</span></label>
 </dt>
<dd>
    <select name="options[3323]" id="select_3323">
     <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
     <option value="9257">Landscape </option>
     <option value="9256">Portrait </option>
   </select> 
   <div class="tagtip-question" id="select_description_3323" style="display:none;"> 
    </div>                                            
</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't know about tags like `<dt>` , `<dd>` but anyway  you can use

```
alert(element.closest('dt').next('dd').find('select').attr('id'))
```